# Running MSTest tests from C#

Tags: mstest

Is it possible to run all tests of a TestClass class using C# code only ? I found that it is possible to run tests using a command line tool called MSTest, but this is not what I am looking for.

I want to run all tests defined in a class, change some parameters and run all tests again. This would be repeated a few times, so it would be nice to do it using C#, as it would be easy to evaluate the test results programmatically.